# Replace file content starts with number) and preserving rest of line content

Tags: sed

I would like to replace file contains special pattern with sed or similar solutions. I can replace file with individual sed but number can be anything and need to preserve prefix as it is.

## Actual file:

```
1) L0 | Delete multiple contacts | C543072
2) L1 | Move Multiple Messages via Header toolbar Move button | C1832588
3) L1 | Move Multiple Messages contains file attachment | C2058412
- L1 | Forward message containing attachment | C1976614
- L0 | Normal message contains file attachment | PREAPPS-1488
- L3 | Forward as signed in message view | C1990347
```

## Expected file:

```
FAILED - L0 | Delete multiple contacts | C543072
FAILED - L1 | Move Multiple Messages via Header toolbar Move button | C1832588
FAILED - L1 | Move Multiple Messages contains file attachment | C2058412
SKIPPED - L1 | Forward message containing attachment | C1976614
SKIPPED - L0 | Normal message contains file attachment | PREAPPS-1488
SKIPPED - L3 | Forward as signed in message view | C1990347
```

## Tried code:

```
sed -i 's/- L/SKIPPED - L/' /report.txt
sed -i 's/1) L0/FAILED - L0/' /report.txt
sed -i 's/[0-9]) L/FAILED - L[0-9]/' /report.txt (doesn't preserve LX)
```

Is there any single command using regex to replace content along with preserving LX where string starts with number) L[number]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple commands in a sed script can be separated by semicolons (`;`).

```
$ sed 's/^[0-9]\+)/FAILED -/; s/^-/SKIPPED -/' file
FAILED - L0 | Delete multiple contacts | C543072
FAILED - L1 | Move Multiple Messages via Header toolbar Move button | C1832588
FAILED - L1 | Move Multiple Messages contains file attachment | C2058412
SKIPPED - L1 | Forward message containing attachment | C1976614
SKIPPED - L0 | Normal message contains file attachment | PREAPPS-1488
SKIPPED - L3 | Forward as signed in message view | C1990347
```

- `^` matches beginning of the input line,
- `[0-9]\+` matches one or more digits.

Comment: Yes, thanks for accepting the question and your solution is excellent! I have included prefix spaces and your code worked very well.